# Access token doesn't contain all the requested scopes

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, msal.js

I have an **angular** application and an **DotNet** core web api application. The web api exposes 2 permissions. The angular has susbscribed to those permissions (see screenshot).

[image]

In the code, I tried this

```
export const loginRequest: { scopes: string[] } = {
  //scopes: ['user.read', 'openid', 'profile'], //--> I commented out this line. 
  scopes: []
};

export const tokenRequest: { scopes: string[] } = {
  scopes: ['api://da8b9450-d9b7-4b7f-9667-fdae9a7c8359/API.Access',
           'api://da8b9450-d9b7-4b7f-9667-fdae9a7c8359/API.Write']
};

consentScopes: [
  ...loginRequest.scopes,
  ...tokenRequest.scopes,
],
```

The access token contain the scopes I didn't ask for, but it is not returning what I asked.

[image]

How do I get the 2 scopes I've requested?

Thanks for helping

## EDIT 1

Here's the configuration

```
auth: {
  clientId: '78803184-e866-4966-b372-d98b4feae898',
  authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/",
  validateAuthority: true,
  redirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/",
  postLogoutRedirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/",
  navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
}
```

## EDIT 2

This is are the requested scopes now. I've removed all the related graph, such as `user.read`, `openid`, and `profile`.

```
{
  popUp: !isIE,
  consentScopes: [
    "api://da8b9450-d9b7-4b7f-9667-fdae9a7c8359/API.Access",
    "api://da8b9450-d9b7-4b7f-9667-fdae9a7c8359/API.Write"
  ],
  unprotectedResources: ["https://localhost:5001"],
  protectedResourceMap,
  extraQueryParameters: {}
}
```

I'm still receive the same scopes, i.e. even after the client to the list of clients for the API.

However, I looked at the request being sent to AZURE AD. This is how it looks like. According to this request, I'm still requesting **user.read**, **openid**, and **profile** although I removed them from the list of requested scopes.

```
Request URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/313200b5-a917-47d1-2233-149b07d5d7b5/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
response_type=token&scope=user.read openid profile&client_id=78803184-e866-54e3-b200-d98b4feae898
&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/
&state=eyJpZCI6IjMwZDJkOGNkLTM2NWUtNGMwOS1iYWY1LTcyZWYyMTU0YWE5ZSIs
InRzIjoxNjExNTUwMDUxLCJtZXRob2QiOiJzaWxlbnRJbnRlcmFjdGlvbiJ9
&nonce=6f25b4e0-71f7-4cde-abf4-cb5545d2507e
&client_info=1&x-client-SKU=MSAL.JS&x-client-Ver=1.4.4
&login_hint=admin@myemail.com
&client-request-id=a68ef0b3-111b-4b1c-a3e7-cdcb075516ca
&prompt=none&response_mode=fragment
```

## EDIT 3

I found this line of code

```
const GRAPH_ENDPOINT = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me';

getProfile() {
   this.http.get(GRAPH_ENDPOINT)
      .toPromise().then(profile => {
          this.profile = profile;
      });
 }
```

Comment: This is normal. What you get is the ms graph api token, which only contains the scope of ms graph api. A token cannot contain the scope of two apis. If you need to get the scope of a custom api, you should get another token.

Answer (score 1):

Move comment to answer:

Like I said in the comments， what you get is the ms graph api token, which only contains the scope of ms graph api. A token cannot contain the scope of two apis. If you need to get the scope of a custom api, you should get another token.

The access token is issued according to the [api audience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims) you want to access, and it is unique! A token can only have one audience, and you cannot use multiple scopes to request access tokens.

One sentence summary:  You cannot make an access token contain `API.Access` `API.Write` `User.Read` **scp claims** at the same time, because these are the scope of two completely different APIs.

Comment: That's not obvious from the tutorial. in my example, the audience value is `"aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"`.  and this is how I'm defining the authority `authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/"`. See update

Comment: @Richard77  audience  `"aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"` is actually ms graph api. I noticed that you request two tokens at the same time in the code, but it will only return you the first token in order , the ms graph token.

Comment: @Richard77  View the resource id of Microsoft Graph api: https://www.shawntabrizi.com/aad/common-microsoft-resources-azure-active-directory/

Comment: is this the reason the request is being made to the graph? `authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/",`? Please, pay attention to the login request array. It's empty as I commented out the line that contains `['user.read', 'openid', 'profile']`.

Comment: @Richard77  No, it has nothing to do with your request url. It is related to your `scope`.

Comment: again, I've removed the line containing `['user.read', 'openid', 'profile']`. At the end, the only scopes that I'm requesting are `api://da8b9450-d9b7-4b7f-9667-fdae9a7c8359/API.Access` and `api://da8b9450-d9b7-4b7f-9667-fdae9a7c8359/API.Write`.  Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: @Richard77  Yes, you should ensure that your token audience is: `"aud": "api://da8b9450-d9b7-4b7f-9667-fdae9a7c8359"`.

Comment: @Richard77  You can refer to my previous answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65800504/is-there-a-way-to-authorize-net-core-3-0-apis-with-jwt-and-also-azure-ad-tokens/65806927#65806927

Comment: thank you for the link.  I applied what you said there. However, I think the problem is still in my code. Please take a look at the latest edit. I provided the request being sent to Azure AD. According to it, I'm still requesting `['user.read', 'openid', 'profile']`. Why is that?

Comment: Please take a look at the last edit. Can I safely deduct that the reason for getting those unwanted scopes? `const GRAPH_ENDPOINT = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me';`?